# keys and values of dynamically generated array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Dated] => 2017-04-01
            [Nadeem] => 1995
            [NadeemKaat] => 40
            [Ali] => 0
            [AliKaat] => 0
            [Usman] => 0
            [UsmanKaat] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Dated] => 2017-04-06
            [Nadeem] => 0
            [NadeemKaat] => 0
            [Ali] => 4800
            [AliKaat] => 96
            [Usman] => 0
            [UsmanKaat] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Dated] => 2017-04-20
            [Nadeem] => 0
            [NadeemKaat] => 0
            [Ali] => 0
            [AliKaat] => 0
            [Usman] => 2100
            [UsmanKaat] => 42
        )

)
```

i want to print out this array values like this:

```
Date          | Nadeem | Ali    | Usman
2017-04-01    | 1995   |        |
2017-04-06    |        | 4800   |
2017-04-20    |        |        |2100
```

i am confuse here how to handle this kind of array, please help me out
i am trying with simply foreach loop

```
foreach ($stock as $key => $value) 
{
 echo $key . $value;
}
```

Comment: What does this give you

Comment: not enough attempt to solve the problem

Comment: @Akin A PHP Error was encountered. Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($stock)) {
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($stock[0] as $key => $value) 
{
    echo '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($stock as $value) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $field) {
        echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: this is working great..but if i want to print only desired values? like i only want to print Date, Nadeem, Ali and Usman

Comment: you can add conditions in foreach like that:

    if (in_array($key2, ['Dated', 'Nadeem', 'Ali'])) {
        echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>';
    }

Comment: but the names are dynamic, any name can come there..how i can handle that situation?

Comment: how you will choose names which you want to display?

Answer (score 1):

> @Shafat Ahmad try this below one:

```
<?php
    $stock = array(
                array(
                        "Dated" => "2017-04-01",
                        "Nadeem" => 1995,
                        "NadeemKaat" => 40,
                        "Ali" => 0,
                        "AliKaat" => 0,
                        "Usman" => 0,
                        "UsmanKaat" => 0
                    ),

                array(
                        "Dated" => "2017-04-06",
                        "Nadeem" => 0,
                        "NadeemKaat" => 0,
                        "Ali" => 4800,
                        "AliKaat" => 96,
                        "Usman" => 0,
                        "UsmanKaat" => 0
                    ),

                array(
                        "Dated" => "2017-04-20",
                        "Nadeem" => 0,
                        "NadeemKaat" => 0,
                        "Ali" => 0,
                        "AliKaat" => 0,
                        "Usman" => 2100,
                        "UsmanKaat" => 42
                    )
            );
?>
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Nadeem</th>
    <th>Ali</th>
    <th>Usman</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($stock as $value) {
    ?><tr>
        <th><?php echo $value["Dated"] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $value["Nadeem"] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $value["Ali"] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $value["Usman"] ?></th>
    </tr><?php
}
```

Comment: i don't like the users who down vote without giving any explaination

Comment: there is array with dynamic keys so hardcoding key like $value["Dated"] is wrong solution

Comment: have you read properly his question ? i know the array will be dynamic but the keys name are constant just read care fully what he wants in the output, he mentioned a headers first that is constant as i did

Answer (score 0):

Try inner loops

```
// print header
foreach ($stock[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key. ' | '
}

// print data
foreach ($stock as $item) 
{
    foreach ($item as $value) {
        echo $value . ' | '
    }
}
```

And then do a little bit play with changing `|` with `<tr>`, `<td>` and so on if you want proper table.

Or you can use

```
$header = array_keys($stock[0]);
echo '<table><tr><th>';
echo implode('</th><th>', $header);
echo '</th></tr>';

// print data
foreach ($stock as $item) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo implode('</td><td>', $item);
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($stock as $data) {
    echo $data['Dated'].'    |    '.($data['Nadeem'] ? $data['Nadeem'] : "") .'    |    '.$data['NadeemKaat'].'    |    '.$data['Ali'].'    |    '.$data['AliKaat'].'    |    '.$data['Usman'].'    |    '.$data['UsmanKaat'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array_keys($some[0]);
$theader = implode("\t", $keys);
echo $theader;
foreach ($some as $one) {
    echo "\n";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        echo $one[$keys[$i]] . "\t";
    }
}
```

Assuming structure of your data doesn't  change  and `$some` is your given above array

Output :

```
Dated       Nadeem  NadeemKaat  Ali AliKaat     Usman   UsmanKaat
2017-04-01  1995    40          0       0       0       0   
2017-04-06  0       0           4800    96      0       0   
2017-04-20  0       0           0       0       2100    42
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample program. Maybe it'll help you.

```
// user data can be dynamic
$userData = array('Nadeem', 'Ali', 'Usman');

// tblRows data can also be dynamic
$tblRowsData = array(
        '2017-04-01' => array('Nadeem'=>1995, 'Ali'=>'', 'Usman'=>''),
        '2017-04-06' => array('Nadeem'=>'', 'Ali'=>4800, 'Usman'=>''),
        '2017-04-20' => array('Nadeem'=>'', 'Ali'=>'', 'Usman'=>2100)
    );

echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Date</td>";
        foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";


    foreach ($tblRowsData as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$key</td>";

            foreach ($userData as $key1 => $value1) {
                echo "<td>".$value[$value1]."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shit coded, fast written solution)))

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $value) {
    foreach($value as $person => $count) {
        if($person !== 'Dated') {
            $data[$value['Dated']][$person] = $count;
        }
    }
}

if(!$data) {
    die('empty');
}

$persons = array_keys(reset($data));


$html = '<table border="1"><thead>
  <th>Date</th>';

foreach($persons as $key) {
    $html .= "<th>{$key}</th>";
}
$html .= '</thead><tbody>';

while($temp = array_splice( $data, 0, 1 )) {
    $date = array_keys($temp)[0];
    $html .= "<tr><td>".$date."</td>";
    foreach($persons as $name) {
        $val = isset($temp[$date][$name]) ? $temp[$date][$name] : '-';
        $html .= "<td>".$val."</td>";
    }
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= '</tbody></table>';
die($html);
```

Where input like

```
$input = [
    [
        'Dated' => '2017-04-01',
        'Nadeem' => 1995,
        'NadeemKaat' => 40,
        'Ali' => 0,
        'AliKaat' => 0,
        'Usman' => 0,
        'UsmanKaat' => 0
    ],
    [
        'Dated' => '2017-05-11',
        'Nadeem' => 123,
        'NadeemKaat' => 40,
        'Ali' => 3,
        'AliKaat' => 0,
        'Usman' => 0,
        'UsmanKaat' => 0
    ]

];
```

Output in HTML:
[image]